# Is it possible to avoid call to sotring within the partiton during the usage of Dataframe.write.partitionBy(<partition column>)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

*Is it possible to avoid the call to internal sorting within the partitonBy function during the usage of Dataframe.write.partitionBy().parquet(path: String) because this df is already in sorted order.*

***Explanation:***

At run 1: we are reading all the base data and storing it into partitioned folders on top of s3

```
step1) BaseData -> sparkJob ->  s3(partitioned data)
```

At run 2:
step1) we are reading the delta data then re-partitioning and sorting it up.
step2) union the delta with basedata and saving it to the s3 location(partitioned).

```
step 1) DeltaData -> Sparkjob(repartition(by same partition number) + sortByPartition(<partition col>) )

step 2) BaseData(s3 partitioned) -> spark( BaseData union refined delta df(step 1)) ->  s3(partition data)
```

Now, I am using ***DF.write.partitionBy(part col).parquet(path: String)*** function to write the data to s3 which is calling the sort stage internally. I need to avoid this sorting, is there a way?